# Laravel Virtual Host throws TokenMismatchException

Tags: apache, laravel, laravel-5

I have created a virtual host on apache for Laravel Project. And it is working perfectly. But here the issue is that It throws me `TokenMismatchException` on submit a form.

But when I run `php artisan server` and submit form on url `localhost:8000`. Then It works perfectly.

I did not understand why it throws `TokenMismatchException` error at virtual host url only.

Here is the how I created virtual host.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin admin@example.com
        ServerName tutslaravel.dev
        ServerAlias www.tutslaravel.dev
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/tutslaravel/public
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
    DirectoryIndex index.php index.html index.htm
    <Directory "/var/www/html/tutslaravel/public">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        Allowoverride All
                Order allow,deny
                Allow from all
                Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Have you attach `csrf_token` in your form ?

Comment: @Danish Yes, I have used `csrf_token` in form.  This issue only happen at virtual host url. It is working absolutely fine at `localhost:8000`

Comment: I'm using Laravel with virtualHost it works fine, I could provide you an example, but when using an application inside another with alias it keeps returning the TokenException

Comment: I found a solution for my case, I should add in .htaccess a RewriteBase /sub_app